# How to suppress "import" statements in IntelliJ regex search?

Tags: regex, intellij-idea, search, import

I like to search in IntelliJ for all occurrences of `lecture*` and `event` in source code files. This works with the `(lecture*|event)` regex statement as shown in the screenshot.

[image: IntelliJ / Find in Path / Regex search]

Now I would like to filter out all `import` statements which also contain one or more of the terms in order to focus on the remaining code locations. How do I have change the regular expression to get the desired result?

Comment: Try `\bimport .*(?:lecture\*|event)`

Comment: If you wanna filter imports out, you could use a negative lookahead somehow like that: `^(?!import)`. Or the full version could be `^(?!import)\s.*(lecture|event)`

Comment: @Thefourthbird Your expression highlights all imports which contain the term `event`. I aiming at the opposite.

Comment: @vepanimas Your expression works okay. There are still some imports highlighted which have an empty line above. Both the empty line and the import with term `event` are match is such a case.

Comment: @JJD You could use `^(?![^\S\r\n]*import ).*\b(?:lecture\*|event)\b` to match no newlines before https://regex101.com/r/N3Yl4q/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use exclude matching import at the start of the string using a negative lookahead.

```
^(?![^\S\r\n]*import ).*\b(?:lecture\*|event)
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert what is on the right is not

  - `[^\S\r\n]*import`  Match 0+ times a whitespace char except newlines, match import and space
- `)` Close lookahead
- `.*` Match any char except a newline 0+ times
- `\b(?:lecture\*|event)` Match either lecure* or event preceded by a word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5O1o6x/1)

**Note** to escape the `\*` or else this part `lecture*` will match match `lectur` followed by 0+ repetitions of the `e` char.

Comment: Thanks! Almost perfect - and definitely good enough to work with. - Is there a change that only the actual term is highlighted not the line from its start?

Comment: @JJD Not sure if it is supported, but you could try a quantifier in a lookbehind `(?<=^(?![^\S\r\n]*import ).*?)\b(?:lecture\*|event)` or with a finite quantifier `(?<=^(?![^\S\r\n]*import ).{0,1000})\b(?:lecture\*|event)`